# Getting list of all SQL users from multiple servers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an task of getting the user reconciliation where we have around 50 SQL servers, I need to take the list of database users from all the SQL servers in one place and mail it to team. Any ideas will be helpful and I have SCOM server also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any quick or fancy way, but you could do:

```
;with ServerPermsAndRoles as
(
    select
        spr.name as principal_name,
        spr.type_desc as principal_type,
        spm.permission_name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as security_entity,
        'permission' as security_type,
        spm.state_desc
    from sys.server_principals spr
    inner join sys.server_permissions spm
    on spr.principal_id = spm.grantee_principal_id
    where spr.type in ('s', 'u')

    union all

    select
        sp.name as principal_name,
        sp.type_desc as principal_type,
        spr.name as security_entity,
        'role membership' as security_type,
        null as state_desc
    from sys.server_principals sp
    inner join sys.server_role_members srm
    on sp.principal_id = srm.member_principal_id
    inner join sys.server_principals spr
    on srm.role_principal_id = spr.principal_id
    where sp.type in ('s', 'u')
)
select *
from ServerPermsAndRoles
order by principal_name
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx

On each of the servers, and stuff the results in a single Excel spreadsheet - then using Excel, filter only unique entries.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and help , running this query will get the user details of all the SQL servers that are available?

Comment: My Exact requirement is , I have 50 SQL servers , I need to run an script either poweshell or by SSMS , where I get all the Database users details in local disk as csv

Comment: It will give you the users for a single server.  Meaning, you'd need to run the code on each server - so 50 times in your case.  Unfortunately I don't know of any magic way of accessing servers unless all 50 are accessible through a linked-server configuration - but even then, you'll probably need to run the script 50 times. Maybe if you have access to a developer, they can knock something up where you can declare in a config file the servers and it will automatically run the script against each server? - really only useful if it's going to be a regular request.

Comment: thanks for your support , let us see if any one else can help me using powershell